# Equation Number Overwriting

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, subequations

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{Ultheses}
\addtolength{\footskip}{0.25in}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabu} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {/} }
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
%\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
%\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage[intoc,refpage]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\renewcommand{\pagedeclaration}[1]{\dotfill\hyperpage{#1}}
\newcommand{\nm}[2]{\nomenclature{#1}{#2}}
%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{epsfig} %% for loading postscript figures
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
%\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{mydef}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
```

I have use these packages. Its my thesis. I don't know which part of the code should I upload here?

How can I remove the overwriting of equation numbers? I have not labelled all the equations however after properly labeling the equation number the problem remains. How can this problem be fixed?
[image]

Comment: how we can reproduce your problem if you not provide equation code? please edit your question and add small but complete document with your equation beginning with  `\documentclass{...}`˙and end with `\end{document}`. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Take a look at the following to learn how to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) In short: Post code that is enough to recreate your issue, but nothing more. So the display environment you used to typeset that formula and all packages necessary to use that code snippet. And make sure that the posted code actually shows your issue.

Comment: you upload only preamble. you  should add code of equation too. your error is untypical and you doing something very wrong. however until we not see equation code, we cant say anything.

Comment: And in the editor for your question you can highlight the code and click on the `{}` button to mark it as code (as I did in my edit for you).

Comment: Is the `Ultheses` document class available online somewhere? Likewise, what does the `mydef` package contain?

Comment: I don't know how it works in the backend code. It follows the ULL thesis class. There is a zip file for the ULLclass on this link. This is the link for the Ullthesis class: https://interval.louisiana.edu/thesis-class/ULL-thesis-class-explanation.html

Comment: The link you provided eventually leads to a document class file called `ullthesis2017.cls`. Is that the same as `Ultheses.cls` that your code would appear to employ?

Answer (score 5):

The file `ullthesis2017.cls` -- which may or may not be functionally the same as `Ultheses.cls` -- contains the instructions

```
\@addtoreset {equation}{chapter}
\renewcommand\theequation
    {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@equation}
```

This code indicates that you should not be providing the instruction

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

in the preamble of your thesis document. For sure, if one comments out this instruction, the unfortunate equation number overprinting issue vanishes.

[image]

If I were in your shoes, I would mostly strive to find an alternative to the `ullthesis2017` (or `Ultheses`) document class. Really.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{ullthesis2017} % same as 'Ultheses.cls'?
%% I've simplified the preamble considerably...
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\numberwithin' macro
\numberwithin{equation}{section} % see what happens if you comment out this line...

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solved the problem of equation overwriting. thanks a ton!!!! Huge problem solved!!!

Comment: I'm very fast. Good answer +1.

Comment: @Abhijeet - The *real solution* would consist mainly in not using such a dreadful mess of a LaTeX document class.

Comment: I am new to Latex. The graduate school provided me the  template. I am slowly and steadily learning LaTeX. I will definitely code it on my own in the future.

Comment: I see no problem in the code using `\ifnum`.

Comment: @egreg - I realize I expressed myself rather poorly: Other code in the document class overrides the effect of the `\ifnum...\fi` code; hence, the conditional is nothing but deadwood. I'll edit my answer to omit the (apparently less than fully helpful...) aside.

Answer (score 2):

- your document class is unknown to me, so i cant test your code.
- with standard `documentclass` as is `article,`report`or`book` is not possible reproduce your problem. for example

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}%{Ultheses}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
   \MoveEqLeft
xxxx = 1 + yyyyy + zzzzz    \\
      &   - uuuuuu - vvvvvvv
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

please test this minimal document example with your document class and see, i you will obtain your error.

Comment: Also for you +1.

Comment: It's some bizarre code in the document class used by the OP that's responsible for the overprinting issue. See my answer for more details. The "remedy", such as it is, consists of omitting the otherwise-standard instruction `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`.

Comment: @Mico, +1 for your answer. it is difficult believe, that exist such `documentclass`es. i sympathize with everyone they need to use them.